# Android WifiManager: How to store wifi scan results for multiple scans

Tags: android, arraylist, wifimanager

I need to do multiple scans using WifiManager. I have the following code to scan only once and store the results in access_points, can anyone suggest an efficient code to store results of multiple scans?

```
 wifi = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
 List<ScanResult> access_points = wifi.getScanResults();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong way to get results. If you simply do `List<ScanResult> access_points = wifi.getScanResults();`it will return old results to you.

To get wifi scan results you simply get an instance of WifiManager like you do in the first line and then

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.getScanResults();

// The above is an async call and will results are available System will broadcast SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE intent and you need to set a `BroadCastReceiver` for it.

// And when you catch the intent, get the results using 

List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
```

To get the results multiple times or to do multiple scans you need to simply call `wifiManager.startScan()` multiple times and obtain fresh results using `List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();` when you catch the intent `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE`. You can use a timer for that or use post method of handler.

Comment: thanks, but i want to see exactly how this can be done multiple times with nested loop and the results stored for each call in multiple lists.

Comment: @peter_ziegler Do you have a specific time interval after which you want the results? Or some other criteria?

Comment: yes say for example after every 5 seconds, that is I will do 3 scans in total with an interval of 5 seconds

Comment: why not run a timer and get call wifiManager.startScan and then get results by wifiManager.getScanResults. You don't need to wait for SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE. Calling startScan will automatically update results returned by getScanResults.